# Running a .bash file in Eclipse

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, eclipse

I know this is really an Eclipse issue but I can't seem to login in their forum.
I am running eclipse juno for some c/c++ development.However, I wrote a .bash script that initiate the entire program.As input argument to this script, I have a a configuration file which is one directory lower than the .bash file.

In terminal I just do:

```
./startenb.bash ./CONF/ANNE
```

it runs just fine.

How can I configure the external tools in eclipse to take this file path as input argument?

Any help or old thread vaguely addressing this issue is highly welcome.

Answer (score 6):

The precise answer is going to depend on what the `startenb.bash` file does - in particular whether it needs to be run from a particular directory relative to your eclipse project/build tree (when run in the terminal, where is `./` exactly?) but basically it should just be a matter of using the `Location`, `Working Directory`, and `Arguments` boxes in the 'External Tools Configurations' window.

For example, if I have a script in my `~/Documents` directory that just prints its working directory and (first) argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "current directory: $PWD"

echo "running with argument ${1:-[none]}"
```

then setting

[image: eclipse screenshot]

allows me to run

[image: eclipse screenshot]

Comment: Steeldriver, simply put, you are a life saver.For two days now I have been struggling with this issue.The mistake I was doing was that I wasn't putting the working directory.I didn't know what that means.Based on your explanation above, I did it this morning and it works like a charm.Thanks

Comment: Another quick question, everything is working fine now but it doesn't recognize my breakpoint.Is there a possibility to configure the a bash script(external tool) to run in debug mode so that it take cognizance of the breakpoints?Thanks

Comment: Sorry - I've never tried to set Eclipse breakpoints in a bash script. The best I can suggest is that you add a `set -x` directive to the script itself to make debugging easier (`-x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.` - see `help set` from the bash prompt).

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to run a few commands, you don't need to write a shell script.

1. Create a new external tool configuration
2. Set Location to `/bin/sh`
3. Set Arguments to `-c "list; of; commands"`